# Read the DOM of an uploaded page using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to develop a functionality where I should be able to read the DOM of a page using PHP. The page can be uploaded using an interface.

My intent is to actually read through the HTML and list out all the containers present in the HTML page.

Need some suggestions on how to go about it.

Stressing on that I want to be able to identify the elements on the page and make a list of all the elements present.

Comment: Anserws here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use libraries like this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Read the content of the uploaded file and than you can manipulate it.

If you want more information on that you should try it out and than ask specific questions as SO is not a tutorial-page.